# Omit magic comment from YARD docs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yard

I have the magic comment `# -*- encoding : utf-8 -*-` at the top of every ruby file in my Rails app. Thing is, it shows up in my YARD docs in the Overview section of each class definition:

```
Overview

-*- encoding : utf-8 -*- The Book model contains a number of   #etc
```

Is there a way I can omit it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you remove this magic comment and format your file to `UTF-8`?